# How to read GSM AT command response on arduino Serial port for long response?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, gsm, at-command, sim800l

I have Arduino UNO and a Sim800L module and I know the way to read the serial, it is something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884514/get-at-command-response), but when I perform this function :

```
    String GetRegData()
    {
      Serial.println("Get nearby antenna info ...");
      SIM800L.print("AT+CNETSCAN=1\r");
      delay(1000);

      SIM800L.print("AT+CNETSCAN\r"); 
      delay(1000);

      String buffer2;

      while (SIM800L.available())
       {
          char c = SIM800L.read();
          Serial.print(c);
          buffer2.concat(c);
          delay(10);
       }
       //Serial.println();
       return buffer2;
    }
```

The output is :

```
AT+CMGF=1

OK
AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0

OK
AT+CNETSCAN=1

OK
AT+CNETSCAN

Operator:"XXXX",MCC:XXX,MNC:XX,Rxlev:XX,Cellid:XX,Arfcn:XX,Lac:q5er32xlAair32xlAacrseifcca,Nvdc00
```

This AT command (**AT+CNETSCAN**) should scan all nearby antenna and print some information in multiple lines(according to datasheet), when I execute this command manually on this devices(SIM800L) ,I get multiple line such :

```
Operator:"XXXX",MCC:XXX,MNC:XX,Rxlev:XX,Cellid:XX,Arfcn:XX,Lac:XX,Bsic:XX
Operator:"XXXX",MCC:XXX,MNC:XX,Rxlev:XX,Cellid:XX,Arfcn:XX,Lac:XX,Bsic:XX
Operator:"XXXX",MCC:XXX,MNC:XX,Rxlev:XX,Cellid:XX,Arfcn:XX,Lac:XX,Bsic:XX
OK
```

But I don't know what happen when I do it programmatically, It is messed up, I tried to change baud rate and change receiving method and read char by char and I did put delaying between receives and I tried to do `if` or `for` instead of `while`  but no luck.

I guess there is a delay between receiving each line and it breaks the serial availability but I don't know what to do ! any help would be appreciated.

By the way, my setup function:

```
void setup() {
  SIM800L.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  delay(3000);

  SIM800L.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); 
  delay(100);

  SIM800L.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
  delay(100);
  GetRegData();

  delay(1000);
}
```

**Ps**: The whole thing(Arduino+Sim800L) works perfectly fine with no error and the Simcard is unlocked and it can send an receive SMS and Calls ,etc.

Comment: So you are complaining about the response that seems corrupted in the "LAC" field of the first line?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Yes, it seems, something bad happens near LAC field and the rest of the lines ,are not printing or saving in the variable.

Comment: Does the 'X' in `Operator:"XXXX",MCC:XXX,MNC:XX,Rxlev:XX,Cellid:XX,Arfcn:XX,Lac:...` substitute 1vs1 the actual chars? What is the first unexpected character in the response? Is that message printed by the  `Serial.print(c);` or by another external call printing buffer2?

Comment: What I noticed is that the output is strange after about 64 characters. PS:serial.read() returns an int type variable (and -1 on error, so you shoud check its return value)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni the output is like ::Operator:"405803",MCC:405,MNC:803,Rxlev:62,Cellid:51A5,Arfcn:702    and serial print nothing.

Comment: Now I'm getting confused: does it print what you showed in your question or nothing at all?

Comment: no I put X for each digit, the sample I've commented was a full response sample of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By spending hours of thinking the whole process through, I came up with an idea:

**Be at Serial port for 10 second and get what ever it spit out! 
NO Serial port breaking out NO `while (SIM800L.available() != 0)`**

The `elapsedMillis` is the library and this is the code:

```
String buffer2;

elapsedMillis timeElapsed;
unsigned int interval = 10000; 

while(timeElapsed < interval){
    if (SIM800L.available() != 0){ // for ignoring the NULLs
        char c = SIM800L.read();
        Serial.print(c);
        buffer2.concat(c);
      }
}
```

*Although there are some highlights in this process :*

1- The main reason for NOT getting the whole output by the old loop is , the `SIM800L.available()` became Zero during multiple line receiving!

2- The `String` data type or `SIM800L.read();` Do NOT do anything wrong and they, theoretically have no limitation of reading device output(Like 64 byte ) characters , They read it all

3- Some times electronic devices act strangely special Sim800L which is old and cheap!

4- If you will to send this data(Network Antenna Scan) via SMS, be aware of SMS max character limit and consider that Service Providers will charge you for about every 150 char that send! and remove `\r\n` chars from response, and  run `AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0` before sending SMS on SIM800L otherwise it will send a blank SMS!

5- **Sim800L** Datasheet said it work best on port **115200** *BUT* it is too fast for this device! set its baud rate on **9600**.

Comment: Ok, so you didn't wait enough to read all the response. What you found is just a workaround. What you need is to find the correct delay and  strategy to read. Since you wait for a delay of only 10ms, returning after the first `serial.available() == 0` it is probably too quick. What you probably should do is waiting until at least 200ms withouch input chars.

Comment: Talking about baudrates: 115200 is the default speed in modems since about 2000. The problem is probably on Arduino side (receiving from a faster serial is more difficult, and there are also HW consequences, since current consumption is bigger).

Comment: Finally in code attached it is not clear how `timeElapsed` is updated in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Two tips:

- Get rid of the ALL delay()s in your receive function it stops processing for 10 millis each character which might sum up to a serial buffer overflow on the long run
- Get rid of String class, read into a char buffer large enough to take the largest expected message. Examples may be found here on stackexchange.

The serial.available() is handy if you do two way com, but you need to do your own checking for end terminators or other external signals.

Comment: I did remove delay in read and I've tried to read char by char but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to OP's answer, the problem resides on `serial.available()` returning 0 and making the loop end too early.

That probably happens because the delay between two consecutive `serial.read()` calls is too low, and it is not enough to wait for some side scenarios such as an AT response presented in more lines.

Increasing that delay would be wrong, because response is read character by character, and that change would affect the total time. What can be done is exiting the loop after a total *inter-character delay* . It the following example the value of `200ms` is used:

```
#define MAX_DELAY_MS  200
#define LOOP_DELAY_MS 10

String GetRegData()
{
  int intercharTime = 0;

  Serial.println("Get nearby antenna info ...");
  SIM800L.print("AT+CNETSCAN=1\r");
  delay(1000);

  SIM800L.print("AT+CNETSCAN\r"); 
  delay(1000);

  String buffer2;

  while (  intercharTime < MAX_DELAY_MS  )
   {
      if( SIM800L.available() )
      {
          int c = SIM800L.read();

          /* read() return -1 on fail. Make sure it read something before using c */
          if( c != -1 )
          {
              Serial.print( (char)c );
              buffer2.concat( (char)c );

              /* Something received: reset intercharTime */
              intercharTime = 0;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          intercharTime += LOOP_DELAY_MS;
      }

      delay(LOOP_DELAY_MS);
   }

   //Serial.println();
   return buffer2;
}
```

### Changes:

- `intercharTime` is checked to exit the loop. It is increased each time `serial.available()` returned 0. Resetted each time a character is received. In this way we exit the loop after `MAX_DELAY_MS` milliseconds.
- `read()`  returns an integer, so I placed it on an integer variable, casting it to `char` whenever required. Furthermore it returns -1 on failure. It is always better to check return values before manipulating data that might be invalid.
- I also substituted `10ms` delay with a define. In this way it will be easy to play with several couples of `LOOP_DELAY_MS` and `MAX_DELAY_MS` in order to find the best fit.