# Active Caller ID feature using TAPI 2

Tags: c++, tapi

I have written a small software to show caller id using c++ and TAPI 2 library.
I have used a lineInitializeEx function to initialize a modem , and lineOpen function to open a modem line, ..etc.

My question is, how can I activate a caller id on my modem?
I know I must use an AT command "AT+VCID=1" which worked correctly using a putty software, but how can I send this command in my software using the TAPI library?
Any function?

Comment: I remember starting a project on this subject 25+ years ago. I wanted to make it a shareware product when shareware was very much a thing..

Comment: Maybe this helps: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49057262/sending-at-commands-to-usr-modem-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49057262/sending-at-commands-to-usr-modem-in-c)